# Which 2014 TurboTax Edition Do I Need?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

I'm having trouble understanding which version of TurboTax I need to do my personal taxes.  I don't know if the online and CD editions are equivalent, but I'm planning on getting the CD edition since I tend to see better sales on them.

I have an S-Corp, and purchased TurboTax Business for my corporate taxes.

Other facts:

- Own a home
- No stock sales or purchases this year (outside of retirement accounts)
- Married filing jointly
- No dependents
- No other businesses

The TT product selector is very confusing.  If I say I have a corporation, it recommends TT Business.  If I say I "Own a Business/Sole Proprietorship", it recommends Home and Business (which includes Schedule C).  If I select neither, it recommends Deluxe, but in reading the details it appears that Deluxe doesn't include Schedule E.

So do I need Premier, which is not recommended unless I indicate that I sold stocks or bonds, or own rental property, neither of which is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Premier, since it is [the first one to include Schedule E](https://turbotax.intuit.com/personal-taxes/irs-forms/). [Deluxe used to support Schedule E](https://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/a-quick-follow-up-on-turbo-tax-deluxe-edition/) for investments, but not anymore. Most taxpayers know Schedule E as the schedule used for rentals, but you're going to need it to report your S-Corp income.

Comment: It is interesting that the [comparison chart you linked to](https://turbotax.intuit.com/personal-taxes/irs-forms/) shows Schedule C as available in Deluxe, but [Intuit's official apology letter](https://turbotax.intuit.com/modals/goodwill-letter/) acknowledges that Schedule C was removed from Deluxe.  Having been a long-time TurboTax user for many years, I'm using H&R Block software for the first time this year.

Comment: Yep, I agree, they really screwed up on this one.

Answer (score 0):

In November '14, I wrote [TurboTax 2014 Marketing Mistake](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/turbotax-2014-marketing-mistake/) 
Shortly after writing it, a TurboTax agent wrote (on Amazon) to counter the complaints by saying that Deluxe has these forms but did not offer Interview help for them. 
As Ben notes in his comment on LittleAdv's answer. TurboTax issued an apology letter, which, in my opinion, didn't really set things straight, factually.

The forms are there, the interview and data import for stock transactions is gone.

Comment: This just popped up on my deal alert from a popular deal site:  https://turbotax.intuit.com/25back.  Looks like they are trying to do some damage control.

Comment: @PhilSandler - agreed. Better still would be to let Deluxe users upgrade to Premiere via download. Having to buy the upgrade to apply for a rebate is just more wasting my time. I like TurboTax, and at least this is a start.